# Shimano Tourney Front Derailleur Cable Question

Tags: derailleur-front

I'm trying to install a new front derailleur cable on an old mountain bike I've been helping to fix up for a friend. The derailleur is a bog-standard Shimano Tourney.

After removing the old cable and threading the new one through to where the derailleur is, I've realised I can't remember how the cable is attached! I'm not sure if it just fixes directly to the bolt or if it kind of wraps around part of the derailleur before going to the bolt.

I've attached a few photos to show both sides of the derailleur. Could anyone tell me exactly where the cable goes?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this help ? https://si.shimano.com/#/en/DM/GN0001

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't change anything except the cabling, that is a bottom-pull system, because the cable comes up from below.  The other system is a top-pull, and is less common.

When the derailleur is at rest, the internal spring is pulling the cage toward the middle of the bike, making it a "low-normal" which is again most common.

Upshot - there is an arm on the derailleur that will move down as you manually pull the chain-cage out to the right.  Your inner cable needs to pull that arm down.

I would try like this:

[image]

It is possible to put the cable the other way around the pinch bolt, which may help with angles, but that little step-lip is probably to help define the pivot point.

Front derailleurs are fiddly things to set up perfectly.  If you haven't moved it on the frame, and have not changed the limit screws, then that makes it a bit easier.   Good luck!